# Is it possible to find a random element in a Set in Constant time?

Tags: algorithm, hashmap, time-complexity, hashset

So, I ran across a problem for building a set with a getRandomElement() function. Easy enough at first glance. But the more I think about this, the less I think it’s possible to do this in O(1) time complexity. There was no given requirement for constant time, but all of a sets major functionality is in constant time, so I feel like it’s implied that this should also be accomplished in constant time.

The goal of a set is for the hashing function to reduce collisions. The problem now becomes that if you simply generate random integers and try to select the index using this random integer, you will most likely run into an “empty” slot in your set....in which case you must generate a new random number and try again. Essentially the better your hashing function, the worst your getRandomElement will perform using this approach.

So then I thought...okay, why not store the indices after every insertion? Then, generate a random number and select  an index from this collection of indices. I thought this was a good idea, but then comes the problem of removing elements. We would also have to remove the corresponding index from our index list, as well as removing the element itself from our Set. How can we find the correct index to remove any faster than linear time???

Anyway, getting a random element from a set FEELS like it can be done in better than linear time. Btw, I’m handling collisions by chaining. I don’t want to waste time trying to do what’s mathematically impossible, but I’m also not a mathematician and I don’t want to give up on something that actually is possible.

Comment: It isn't quite clear what your problem is. What does *building a set with a getRandomElement() function* entail exactly? Show some (pseudo)code and explain how its behaviour is not satisfactory.

Comment: I don’t necessarily have a problem. My question is essentially can getting a random element be accomplished faster than linear time. I don’t really need code, or a coded solution to a problem.

Comment: So you want to get a random element from a given set, rather than build a set out of anything. Would that be a correct wording?

Comment: So we can build this set however we want. It just must support the basic functionality of a set, but also needs to have a getRandomElement function. In theory you should be able to insert, remove, etc. getRandomElement should return a random element from the set that was previously inserted.

Comment: To answer your question, the set must be built, and is not given.

Comment: Oh you want to build a data structure that supports set operations and also a getRandomElement operation faster than in linear time, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly correct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is possible to build a set-like data structure that supports O(1) getRandomElement operation. You are right about storing elements in an array. The problem of removing elements is not too difficult.

The secret is to compress the array once the number of holes is too large (say, more than half of the size of the array). This way the amortised deletion time is still O(1).

When performing `getRandomElement()`, just repeat until you hit an actual element. The mean number of repetitions is no more than 2, because the array is always at least half-full, so you still have your O(1) average time for `getRandomElement()`.

Edit: perhaps a simpler method of deleting elements would be to move the last element to the vacated place.

Comment: Ahhh, ok. Yes, this makes perfect sense. I overoptimized in trying to reduce collisions but even still, the mean number of repetitions is still constant. Not sure why that went over my head, or why I thought generating another random in the event of an “empty” slot would send me down some endless path of generating randoms, lol. Thanks!